# how to convert seconds to minutes using javascript...?

Tags: javascript

I am making a online quiz system and i want to convert my timer from seconds to minutes and seconds. Please help me to solve this problem here is my code

```
<div id="divCounter"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(localStorage.getItem("counter")){
        if(localStorage.getItem("counter") <= 0){
            var value = 110;
        }
     else{  
         var value = localStorage.getItem("counter");
     }
}
else{
    var value = 10;
}

var counter = function (){
document.getElementById('divCounter').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("counter");
if(value <= 0){
        window.location="http://www.google.com"
    }else{
       value = parseInt(value)-1;
       localStorage.setItem("counter", value);
    }
};
var interval = setInterval(function (){counter(value);}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
function convert(value) {
    return Math.floor(value / 60) + ":" + (value % 60 ? value % 60 : '00')
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgno1hn1/3/)

Comment: will you please send me a complete programe.
Actually I am new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

value/60 + ":" + value%60, formats to (m)m:ss figure out the right padding

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you simply use this function (taken from [here](https://github.com/sgmonda/stdio/blob/876aaf1df92a093014660e025d3f323b0615ba45/lib/progress.js)) which transforms a number of seconds into an string representing the hours, minutes and seconds in format HH:MM:SS:

```
function secondsToTimeString(seconds) {
    var minutes = 0, hours = 0;
    if (seconds / 60 > 0) {
        minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60, 10);
        seconds = seconds % 60;
    }
    if (minutes / 60 > 0) {
        hours = parseInt(minutes / 60, 10);
        minutes = minutes % 60;
    }
    return ('0' + hours).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + minutes).slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + seconds).slice(-2);
}
```