# How to convert "seconds" to mm:ss:ll in Adobe (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe, acrobat

Having a complete brain freeze here.

In Adobe Acrobat (javascript):

I have a variable that's in seconds. Example: 92.5

I need it converted to 1:32.50

TIA

Comment: Are you sure you want `92.5` to be `1:32:50` and not `1:32.50`, with a dot? I have only seen the second format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert seconds to minutes using javascript...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29341003/how-to-convert-seconds-to-minutes-using-javascript)

Comment: Let me know if my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to split your seconds into two components: the number of full minutes, and the number of seconds remaining.

**Minutes:**
There are 60 seconds in a minute, so we can determine how many minutes fit into a given number of seconds by dividing the seconds by 60 (`minutes = seconds/60`). Since you want to show the minutes as a whole number instead of a decimal, you'll want to round the result down using `Math.floor(minutes)`.

**Seconds:** You just need to grab the number of seconds left over, so you can subtract `minutes * 60` from your original number, or use the modulus operator (`seconds % 60`—"remainder of seconds divided by 60"). Then you'll probably want to pad it with an extra zero if the value is less than 10.

```js
var minutesAndSeconds = function(seconds){
  //Get the remaining seconds after dividing by 60
  var remainingSeconds = (seconds%60)
  //If less than 10, zero pad
  if(remainingSeconds < 10){
    remainingSeconds = '0'+remainingSeconds
  }
  //Add minutes (number of seconds divided by 60, rounded down) and remaining seconds
  return Math.floor(seconds/60)+':'+remainingSeconds
}

var seconds = 92.5
console.log(seconds, minutesAndSeconds(seconds))
```